# Getting null pointer exceptions when passing around custom pipeline options in google dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In the google dataflow documentations one can easily create custom options and register them in or using the pipeline factory.

However when trying to do this and initializing the custom options object , I end up getting a null pointer exception when calling them in the processing logic that runs on google cloud. Must I pass this around in the context or is it possible to pass it around in any other way?

I tried passing it in some object and ran into serialization errors.

Here are the serialization errors for the sake of clarity.
[image: The serialization error]

Comment: Can you share more about the NullPointerExceptions you're getting? The use of PipelineOptions is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#creating-custom-options. It should be automatically available within the ProcessContext of any DoFn.

Comment: Thanks Ben , I actually used that documentation for using the PipelineOptions but then I could not pass it as an argument to some method that is being executed / invoked in the cloud, that is where the serializeable / not serializeable story was coming in, I think Lukasz explanation below makes some good sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PipelineOptions was designed to not be Java serializable to prevent users from embedding PipelineOptions within their DoFns, CombineFns, and other user definable functions. This allows for users to get access to PipelineOptions that were modified after their pipeline was constructed such as credentials on the Dataflow worker during execution.

In your case, DoFn exposes a context object that provides [access to PipelineOptions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Context.html#method-detail). For example:

```
static class MyDoFn extends DoFn<String, String> {
   @Override
   public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      MyCustomOptions options = c.getPipelineOptions().as(MyCustomOptions.class);
      ... access my options ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz , I think this explains why when you intialize options say the MyCustomOptions before calling the DoFn you still find the initialized variable null in the DoFn so you have to initialize it again. Thanks, it does make sense.

Comment: Lukasz, I know this is quite old, but seems like it no longer works in newer Beam 2.5 APIs, where I need to "simply" pass PipelineOptions argument to the processor. But I always get null there, never my custom options. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet for what your trying to do and or open a new SO question with the details and link to it?